# Is there a need to recomplie my linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am a beginner learning linux kernel module development. I am following a tutorial that says to recompile my kernel so as to enable various debugging features like forced module unloading e.t.c. Is is okay if I do that? Does it effects my pre-built kernel. In what cases that I am forced to insert a module into a running kernel and the kernel won't allow me to do so?

Comment: Yes you should compile a kernel, just to be familiar with it. And you can choose at boot time which kernel you are booting

Comment: You can run the kernel in a VM, especially if you'll be tinkering in it. It would be much easier and safer, if it crashes, it crashes only the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly okay to compile and install a kernel to do kernel module development. If you are in ubuntu, you can follow the following steps to make sure that you are using the same kernel sources as your booted machine.

Step 1. Find out the linux being used in your booting from /boot/grub/grub.cfg file. Look for the entry agains 'linux ' in the boot option entries that you select while booting up.
Example excerpt : linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=e377a464-92db-4c07-86a9-b151800630c0 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff

Step 2. Look for the name of the package with the same version using the following command.

```
dpkg -l | grep linux | grep 3.13.0-24-generic
```

Example output:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux | grep 3.13.0-24-generic
    ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic                       3.13.0-24.46                                                amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                         3.13.0-24.46                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
    ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                   3.13.0-24.46                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Step 3. Download sources of the package "linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic" to get the same kernel that was used in your PC.

```
$ apt-get source linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
```

Step 4. Use the config file that is available at /boot/ folder as the config file to compile this kernel source

Example : 
    $ ls /boot/config-3.13.0-24-generic (Notice the same version used in this file)

Step 5. Turn on your debugging symbols on this config to do your testing.

Answer (score 0):

Recompiling kernel help us to learn how kernel work.

latest kernel patches can be applied through kernel compile and install.

We can enable debug flag through compilation.

We can remove the not needed code.

Helps to add your own kernel code and test your code.

It is easy to recompile and install the linux kernel but it takes more time if we compile using low speed computer or VM.